# Ransack Search Ajax in Application Layout Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I have a Rails 4.2 app in which I'm using Ransack mixed with Geocoder for search.  I want to use an Ajax (remote: true) for my search to avoid pageloads and changing of the URL.

When I implement this in my index view it works great, but I want to abstract the search box to the application layout file so it's available site wide instead of just on the index view.  When I do this (see code example) I'm able to search just fine, but the problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get the Ajax/Remote: True to work. Here is my code:

**application.html.erb**

```
  <%= search_form_for(@search, url:"/resources", :method => :get, remote: true) do |f| %>
     <%= text_field_tag :location, params[:location], placeholder: "Houston, TX", class: "input-sm form-control" %>
      <%= f.submit "Find", class:'btn btn-sm btn-info' %>
  <% end %>
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
  before_action :build_search
  private
  def build_search
    if params[:location].present?
        @search = Resource.near(params[:location], 100).search(params[:q])
      else
            @search = Resource.search(params[:q])
      end
  end
```

**resources/index.js.erb**

```
$("#mapdisplay").html("<%= escape_javascript render("map") %>");
$("#results").html("<%= escape_javascript render("results") %>");
```

**resources/index.html.erb**

```
<div id="mapdisplay">
    <%= render 'map' %>
</div>
<div id="results">
    <%= render 'results' %>
</div>
```

**resources_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_search_results, only: [:show, :index, :new]
def index
        @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@resources) do |resource, marker|
        marker.lat resource.latitude
        marker.lng resource.longitude
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {}
            format.js {}
        end
  end
private
  def set_search_results
    @resources = @search.result(distinct: true)
  end
```

**resources/_map.html.erb**

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<h4>Resources</h4>
<div id="search">
  <%= render 'search' %>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    <%= link_to "Add", new_resource_path, class: 'btn btn-info btn-medium' %>
</div>
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>
<script>
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({
    provider: {
      disableDefaultUI: true
      // pass in other Google Maps API options here
    },
    internal: {
      id: 'map'
    }
  },
  function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  }
);
</script>
```

**resources/_search.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= search_form_for(@search, :id => "resource_search", remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= text_field_tag :location, params[:location], placeholder: "Houston, TX", class: "input-sm form-control" %>
    <%= f.submit "Find", class:'btn btn-sm btn-info' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**resources/_results.html.erb**

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <% @resources.each do |r| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to "#{r.name}", r %></td><td><%= r.address %></td><td><%= r.notes %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Again, I can get this working in the index view/controller with js and remote: true but when I implement the search box sitewide in the application layout file I cannot use JS/remote: true.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple in my implementation so if anyone has any advice, please let me know. If my question and/or code examples are not clear let me know and I'll explain in further detail.

Comment: What output are you getting when you make AJAX call? Or did you figure it out?

Comment: @AlanKis Unfortunately I havent' figured it out yet.  The output I'm getting is that the action is performed as HTML instead of JS when calling the search form from the application layout.  Inside of the index view of the resource controller it will respond to JS no problem.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the fact that you might not have "#results" in your view. It's in the resources/index, however that will only be available to that template. You can move that to application layout, and you should see something different.